# python-requests multipart/form-data from nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to POST some multipart/form-data encoded data.  The API requires all of the uploaded data to be nested in a single field.  In JSON, it looks like this:

`{
  "image": {
        "data": **binary data**,
        "id": 1234
    }
}`

This works fine when I use a REST client, but I'm having trouble getting this to work with python-requests.  I figured I would have more luck if I used `data` instead of `files` and set the header myself, as there seemed to be some magic conversion behind the scenes if I pass the data with `files`.  I get errors either way.

```
obj = {
  "image": {
        "data": **binary data**,
        "id": 1234
    }
}
requests.post(url, {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}, data=obj) # AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
requests.post(url, files={'files':obj}) # AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I've tried encoding the whole object with `json.dumps`, and encoding just the `image` dictionary.  In both cases, it fails because binary data isn't serializable.

Any help here would be appreciated.  I'm not actually a Python dev, so please forgive me if I've missed something obvious.

Comment: you do not need to encode the data.

Comment: Cool, good to know.  Thanks, @MithileshGupta.  What should the request look like, then?  I feel like I've tried everything and it's not accepting the data.

Comment: I'm confused...you say your data has to be encoded as multipart/form-data, but then you say it has to be JSON, which would typically be sent as application/json. Does this API have any documentation?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  It definitely has to be multipart/form-data. I think I had a reason for trying to JSON encode the data, but I honestly can't recall it at this point.

Comment: What did you try with the `files` parameter? I think something like `files = {'image': ('foo.png', open('foo.png', 'rb'), 'image/png')}` followed by `response = requests.post(url, files=files)` should work.

Comment: Yeah, that would work if the image field were just a single value, but it's a dictionary.

Comment: There's no such thing as a dictionary in HTTP. What exact format does the API expect for the HTTP request? For example, a typical multipart/form-data file upload will have one part, and that part will have a header something like `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="foo"` followed by the actual content of the file.

Comment: Yeah, I used the term "dictionary" metaphorically.  The description at the top of my question is basically copied and pasted from the docs, though there are some other optional fields.  I can successfully post data if I used bracket notation in the field names, ie "image[id]".  This seems to work in python-requests, but now I'm having trouble related to POSTing a ZipExtFile object.  A problem for another question, though.

Comment: "I can successfully post data if I used bracket notation in the field names..." Does that mean you solved your problem? If so, please post an answer with more details. If not, can you link to the documentation or copy-paste the relevant section into your question?